# Oracle timezone convert UTC to PST

Tags: oracle, timezone, timestamp

I have a requirement to check tasks in progress using Scheduled start time (PST)  and scheduled end time(PST) .Datatype is timestamp with timezone for Scheduled start time and scheduled end time .

sysdate ( UTC )should be in between the start and end date to confirm tasks in progress

```
JIRA_KEY  sch_start_time               sch_end_time

1         11/04/2016 1:00:00 AM PST   14/04/2016 2:00:00 PM PST

2         12/04/2016 2:00:00 AM PST   12/04/2016 5:00:00 AM PST

3         12/04/2016 2:00:00 AM PST   14/04/2016 5:00:00 AM PST
```

Expected Output -

```
JIRA_KEY  sch_start_time               sch_end_time

1         11/APR/2016 1:00:00 AM PST   14/APR/2016 2:00:00 PM PST

3         12/APR/2016 2:00:00 AM PST   14/APR/2016 5:00:00 AM PST
```

SYSDATE  is in UTC and as of now is  13/APR/2016 8:15 AM

---

I tried this. But not sure abt the conversion using to_timestamp_tz

```
select JIRA_KEY,To_CHAR( SCH_END_TIME,'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS PM') as SCH_END_TIME
 FROM HW_JIRA_STATUS WHERE  
to_timestamp_tz(SYSDATE,'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS PM') between SCH_START_TIME and SCH_END_TIME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
to_timestamp_tz(SYSDATE,'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS PM')
```

you're implicitly converting SYSDATE to a string using your NLS_DATE_FORMAT, and then converting that string to a timestamp with time zone - but you aren't specifying the time zone, so it will use the database time zone by default (which is what you want anyway).

Relying on NLS settings is dangerous, so you should at least use an expliclt format mask:

```
to_timestamp_tz(to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS PM'),'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS PM')
```

... but you can also [`cast` between data types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions023.htm) without converting to intermediate strings; e.g. to again use the DB server time zone:

```
cast(SYSDATE as timestamp with time zone)
```

You don't need to do any conversion yourself though; you can use SYSTIMESTAMP instead:

```
WHERE SYSTIMESTAMP between SCH_START_TIME and SCH_END_TIME;
```

That is already in the DB server's time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select JIRA_KEY,To_CHAR( SCH_END_TIME,'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS PM') as SCH_END_TIME
FROM HW_JIRA_STATUS 
WHERE systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'PST' between SCH_START_TIME and SCH_END_TIME
```